# Having trouble creating stix2 bundle when a list of SDO are passed

Tags: python

I have a Indicator object and a list (contains list of Notes). When I try to create bundle of them, I get below error.
However, when I just pass the list that contains Notes, it works fine.

Error:

```
InvalidValueError: Invalid value for Bundle 'objects': This property may only 
contain a dictionary or object
```

Code:

```
import datetime
from stix2 import Note, Bundle, Indicator

mem = stix2.MemoryStore()
datetime = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')

ind1 = Indicator(
    indicator_types=['malicious-activity'],
    pattern_type="stix",
    pattern="[file:hashes.MD5 = 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e']",
    valid_from="2017-01-01T12:34:56Z",
)

Note_list = [
    Note(type='note', spec_version='2.1', id='note--830ca0aa-75b7-4526-865c-b4f9ded77735', created_by_ref='identity--f431f809-377b-45e0-aa1c-6a4751cae5ff', created='2020-08-21T20:18:48.839396Z', modified='2020-08-21T20:18:48.839396Z', abstract='Cyber Bulletin Comment 1', content='Issue 1', object_refs=['report--84e4d88f-44ea-4bcd-bbf3-b2c1c320bcb3'], object_marking_refs=['marking-definition--613f2e26-407d-48c7-9eca-b8e91df99dc9']), 
    Note(type='note', spec_version='2.1', id='note--f2362c5a-5c06-40a1-a678-db875dbee714', created_by_ref='identity--f431f809-377b-45e0-aa1c-6a4751cae5ff', created='2020-08-21T20:18:48.840376Z', modified='2020-08-21T20:18:48.840376Z', abstract='Comment 2', content='Issue 2', object_refs=['report--84e4d88f-44ea-4bcd-bbf3-b2c1c320bcb3'], object_marking_refs=['marking-definition--613f2e26-407d-48c7-9eca-b8e91df99dc9']), 
    Note(type='note', spec_version='2.1', id='note--72fe7b65-4055-424f-b201-99e8dde86f86', created_by_ref='identity--f431f809-377b-45e0-aa1c-6a4751cae5ff', created='2020-08-21T20:18:48.840538Z', modified='2020-08-21T20:18:48.840538Z', abstract='Cyber Bulletin Comment 3', content="Issue 3", object_refs=['report--84e4d88f-44ea-4bcd-bbf3-b2c1c320bcb3'], object_marking_refs=['marking-definition--613f2e26-407d-48c7-9eca-b8e91df99dc9'])
]

bundle = Bundle([ind1 , Note_list])
print(bundle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error you provided is only 1 of the 4 you have in this case (4 exceptions in the chain, in the sense of PEP 3134). Full chain looks like this (showing only exception reprs for brevity) and already has a clue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 11; 2 is required

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
ValueError: Cannot convert '[Note(...), Note(...), Note(...)]' to dictionary.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
ValueError: This property may only contain a dictionary or object

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
...
InvalidValueError: Invalid value for Bundle 'objects': This property may only 
contain a dictionary or object
```

A quick look at this says that there's basically something wrong with the `stix2.Note` list passed to constructor of the bundle.

Documentation of `stix2` package isn't extensive about bundles, so I'll point you straight to [the initialiser](https://github.com/oasis-open/cti-python-stix2/blob/2743b90fc0afe45193863d3f43f69b5f95cda6a3/stix2/v21/bundle.py#L23) of `stix2.v21.Bundle`. You can see it's quite flexible and accepts objects or lists of objects from `*args` (and also in fact their dictionary or JSON string representations, which isn't evident from there). But it defentely doesn't accept heterogeneous lists like `[Indicator(...), [Note(...), Note(...), Note(...)]]`.

So correct instantiation of the `stix2.Bundle` is any of:

- `Bundle(ind1, Note_list)`
- `Bundle(ind1, *Note_list)`
- `Bundle([ind1] + Note_list)`